How can I add gaps between edges of this arc?
I'm trying to achieve this look of a gap between the arc and the piece of wood above it. Specifically the black lines produced by the shadows in the gaps. I'm not sure whether to do more geometry or if I could try to do some texture or something similar.

What is the best approach to add the like gaps on the unions of this arc?


Hello, what do you mean by gaps on the unions of this arc?

The black lines produced by the shadows in the gaps. I'm not sure whether to do more geometry or if I could try to do some texture or something similar.

Just separate the meshes in your object and adjust the gap as needed. In this case I exaggerated the gap so you can see the meshes are separate:

But feel free to move them closer together and then give the object a bevel modifier which will give this separation look:


Here's the final look:

